# Is a Windows 7 VPN connection secure?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

Is the VPN client in Windows 7 (or Windows 8) strong enough to be safe to use? Or is it easily cracked and best avoided?

I read XP's VPN client was insecure even back in 2004. So I wonder if the more recent versions of Windows have similar problems with the security of their VPN offerings.

Does anyone here use it or have any thoughts on it? If not, why not? (And what do you use instead?)

Sorry for the vagueness! I'm referring to PPTP

Comment: The OS is irrelevant, it's more a matter of the protocol (PPTP, L2TP, IPsec, OpenVPN, SSL, etc.)

Comment: If you want to know *how* secure it is, this is a better question for the Security Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Ok I'll go check out Security Stack Exchange. Wow this place is a mine of great info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At one point in time it had problems. But Microsoft fixed it back in 1999. Cryptanalysis available of it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/145681/is-the-windows-vpn-secure).

Windows 7 VPN is a very good choice. It is easy to set up, it behaves well, it connects very fast, and integrates excellently with the UI. **But it secure ?** Well it depends on how you configure it. In Windows 7 it supports PPTP, L2TP/IPSec, SSTP and IKEv2, and authenticates with EAP or CHAP/CHAPv2. So the protocols are there. Hear are also two articles from MS how to setup everything with [PPTP (Including EAP/TLS and MS-CHAPv2)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738114%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [L2TP (L2TP does require Certs/PKI)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775490%28WS.10%29.aspx).  So yes it can be set up to be very secure.